# Ипорт C исполняемых файлов и библиотек .so в Android Studio

Tags: android, c, apk

У меня имеется предварительно скомпиленная программа для нужных архитектур, которую мне нужно использовать в java приложении в Android Studio. Программа имеет структуру

```
find ./ -type d
./
./lib
./lib/armeabi-v7a
./lib/x86_64
./lib/arm64-v8a
./lib/x86
./bin
./bin/armeabi-v7a
./bin/x86_64
./bin/arm64-v8a
./bin/x86
```

Проблема в том что я даже не могу добавить эту структуру в проект, чтобы она попала в результирующий apk пакет. Объясните пожалуйста как это делается, лучше с учетом результирующих PATH и LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В `app/src/main/jniLibs` для каждой архитектуры папки:

```
arm64-v8a
armeabi-v7a
x86
x86_64
```

Либо прописать путь к либам в build.gradle (app). По дефолту так:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {         
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']          
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а для бинарных файлов есть стандартный путь, или их тоже положить в  jniLibs?

Comment: Это для бинарных. *.so

Comment: Извините, добавляет файлы *.so успешно, но не добавляет простые исполняемые файлы без расширения. Посоветуйте что сделать?

Comment: Я боюсь, что исполняемые файлы вы все равно использовать не получится, т.к. они не в файловой системе будут и без прав соответственно. Вы можете сложить их в res/raw дальше в приложении написать ручное сохранить куда-то, дать права на исполнение и т.д. нетривиальная задача, тут не подскажу, с таким не сталкивался. Возможно, если вы опишите задачу в отдельном вопросе, кто-нибудь может откликнуться...